# get post thumbnail URL from another database wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, database-connection, wordpress

I want get post thumbnail url from another database connection
 first i use this codes for connect database and get attached file

```
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);
  $query = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ";   
  $result = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

after that i dont know how to get url to use in `<img src="<?php url here ?>">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like

```
  $query = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ";   
  $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
  foreach($results as $result){
       $url = $result['meta_value'] ;
       echo '<img src='.$url. '>';
  }
```